# Why always getting Full authentication is required to access this resource instead of Login popup in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Always getting `Full authentication is required to access this resource` when loading url after implementing the `authenticationEntryPoint` in my code.

Before this working as expected but when given wrong login details the page getting loaded again but not giving proper messages so to prevent that implemented `authenticationEntryPoint` to my code.

Code as below:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());

        http.addFilterAt(getCustomAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

```
public class MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        response.getOutputStream().println(authException.getMessage());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();


    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        setRealmName("localhost");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

}
```

CustomFilter Code:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

  @Autowired
  AuthUsersService authUsersService;

  @Autowired
  public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {

    super(authenticationManager);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      Authentication authResult) throws IOException {

       System.out.println("Successful");

    return;

  }


  @Override
  protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("UN-Successful");

    return;

  }  


}
```

I am not getting why this `Full authentication is required to access this resource` message always coming instead of login popup .

can anyone please help on this.

Comment: See @dur before adding authenticationEntryPoint seems everything okay. After adding that removed this header property WWW-Authenticate=Basic from commence() then login popup is not showing. if added this header property then popup is coming but its loading again when autnetication fails also. hope now its clear to you. thanks

Comment: If you remove `WWW-Authenticate=Basic` you can't login. The popup is part of your browser. It is shown x-times until you get finally a error message. You can't change it, because is is part of your browser.

Comment: then how we can throw error message when login failed due to incorrect credentials. thanks @dur